# Passing values ​from adminapp.py to inputdataform.html does not work

Tags: python, html, api, sqlite, rest

In inputdataform.html, the subject is created as tb_subject and called.

CREATE TABLE "tb_subject" (
"num"   INTEGER,
"subject"   TEXT
)

data as (1, math)
(2, eng), (3, kor) (4, sci) are entered

```
@app.route('/inputdataform')
def inputdata():
    db = sql.connect("mailstudy.db")
    # db.row_factory = sql.Row
    cursor = db.cursor()

    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tb_subject")
    subject = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()    

    return render_template('inputdataform.html', rows=subject)
```

inputdataform.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="{{url_for('inputdata')}}" method="POST">
      <h3>Problem Input</h3>
      Subject : <select name="subject">
                {% for row in rows %} 
                  <option value="{{row.num}}">{{row.subject}}</option>
                {% endfor %}  
                </select><br>
      
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved.

```
<html lang='en'>
  <body>
    <form action="{{url_for('inputdata')}}" method="POST">
      <h3>Problem Input</h3>
      Subject : <select name="subject">
                {% for row in rows %} 
                  <option value="{{row[0]}}">{{row[1]}}</option>
                {% endfor %}  
                </select><br>
                
      <input type="submit" value="submit"><br>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```